# jsp又はthymeleaf導入した場合の記述コストについて

Tags: java, html, jsp, thymeleaf

初めまして。  
表題の内容についての質問させて戴きたいと思います。

htmlを元にjsp作成を行う事作業は大変な作業と聞いています。
まず以下の点が上げられるかと思います。  
1.htmlからjspの変換が大変  
2.モックとして使用できない

thymeleafを導入すればhtmlに近い形で記述できる為そのままモックとして使用でき、2.は解決されると思います。

気になるのは1.の記述する部分です。  
jspを利用した場合と、
thymeleafを利用した場合で記述コストはどれ程違うのでしょうか？

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

[このページ](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thvsjsp.html)が参考になると思います。

ご質問の「記述コスト」が「記述量」を意味するのであれば、[前述のページ](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thvsjsp.html)の2.と3.の例にある通り、Thymeleafの方が若干短く書けますが、大きな差は無いと思います。

「記述コスト」が「学習コスト」を意味するとしても、両者に大きな差は無いと思います。実現できること自体に大きな差は無く、文法が違うだけなので。ただし、Javaの知識が無いWebデザイナーが扱うのであれば、よりHTMLに近く、HTMLとしてブラウザに表示できるThymeleafの方が楽だと思います。

「記述コスト」が「開発コスト」や「保守コスト」を意味するのであれば、[前述のページ](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thvsjsp.html)の4.に書いてある通り、修正した結果を確認する時間が短くなる点や、Javaロジックができていなくても画面を表示できる点などでメリットがあるので、Thymeleafの方がコストは少なくなるはずです。少なくなるといっても半分以下になるというようなことはなく、1、2割削減できるという程度だと思います(個人的な感覚では)。

JSPのメリットとして挙げられるのは、歴史がある分、有識者やWeb上での情報が多いということでしょうか。

ちなみに

> 1.htmlからjspの変換が大変

とありますが、HTMLからJSPをつくること自体は簡単です。拡張子を.htmlから.jspに変えればいいだけなので。そういう意味ではないかもしれませんが...